# Is there a modulo function in idris?

Tags: idris

In Haskell, there are the `mod` and `rem` functions. Are there similar functions in Idris, particularly defined over `Nat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`Prelude.Nat`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Nat.html) there are

```
modNatNZ : Nat -> (y : Nat) -> Not (y = 0) -> Nat
modNat   : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
```

The first one needs a proof that the divisor is not zero, while the second is partial (i. e. can crash during runtime). Practically there is also a proof,

```
SIsNotZ : {x: Nat} -> Not (S x = Z)
```

that a successor cannot be zero. So you can just use `modNatNZ 10 3 SIsNotZ` and the unification system will proof `Not (3 = 0)`. You can see how `modNatNZ` works [here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L303). As `Nat` is always positive, a remainder function would behave the same.

Otherwise, a generic

```
mod : Integral ty => ty -> ty -> ty
```

is defined for all types implementing Integral (e.g. Int).

Comment: Here's a link for modNatNZ that's pinned to a certain commit: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/88e7beac09de1c5eba155c571ed7c50ced8cb130/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L316